# Enter button on Keyboard refreshes rather than submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following html

```
<input type="button" value="Get" onClick="get();">
get(); it is some function declared earlier using javascript
```

I know if the input type is submit it works, but how to make it work for the following?

Enter on Key Board.

get function

```
function get() {
$.post('ass.php', { name: form.name.value },
function(output){
    $('#age').html(output).show();

});
}
```

Comment: When you click the button, what appears in your console?

Comment: Question is unclear. You are saying "Enter Button" does that mean this button click function is not working or you are trying to trigger button click on Enter key on keyboard ?

Comment: You should show the code for your `get()` function in order to get help here

Comment: @Sonesh: Enter key on key board.

Comment: @pablo: here is my get() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do is against standards: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/button "The button state represents a button with no default behavior."

The only solution is to catch keyPress action, with appropriate button code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a `keyup` method, but I'm not sure it will do what you want -- it will detect whether a key has released when the `button` has focus. The only way to intercept the enter key and prevent it from making the form submit will be to use `submit`.